# Out of memory tried to allocate - api youtube php (upload video)

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I want to upload video to youtube using api-youtube latest version
when i upload video size lower than 300M the script work very well
but when i want to ypload video superior than >300M this error appear:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1217134592) (tried to allocate
>   1619703661 bytes) in
>   ...\google-api-php-upload\src\service\Google_MediaFileUpload.php on
>   line ..

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '65048M');
$path_to_video_to_upload = 'video.mp4';///////////////

    // Get the Mimetype of your video
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $path_to_video_to_upload);

    // Build the Needed Video Information
    $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle($title);/////////
     $snippet->setDescription($title);/////////
    $snippet->setTags($tag);/////////
    $snippet->setCategoryId(22);/////////

    // Build the Needed video Status
    $status = new Google_VideoStatus();
    $status->setPrivacyStatus('public'); // or public, unlisted

    // Set the Video Info and Status in the Main Tag
    $video = new Google_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);
    echo "ook";
    // Send the video to the Google Youtube API
    $x = $youtube->videos->insert('snippet,status', $video, array('data' => file_get_contents($path_to_video_to_upload),'mimeType' => $mime_type));
```

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  How big is the video file you are working with?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your php.ini change the memory limit variable.

If you haven't, ask your hosting provider to change it for you.

Maybe your provider (share host) has disabled the

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '65048M');
```

function for stopping you and the others to allocate as much ram as it has on the server.

Comment: I have solve the problem
i used this code
$x= $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video,
      array('mediaUpload' => $media));
and i use class Google_MediaFileUpload